# How to convert a code with select commands made in DOS foxpro into Visual Foxpro?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

code converted from foxpro to visual foxpro does not use SELECT command properly. it use esc rather than return key

```
 SELECT DISTINCT FNAME FROM FIRMS INTO ARRAY ARR
 @ 1, 38 GET FN1 DEFAULT AWARDTY(1) SIZE 1, 40 FROM ARR COLOR SCHEME 7
 READ
 CLEAR
 SELECT DISTINCT PNAME FROM FIRMS WHERE FNAME=FN1 INTO ARRAY ARR
 @ 1, 38 GET PN1 DEFAULT AWARDTY(1) SIZE 1, 40 FROM ARR MESSAGE 'SELECT PARTY NAME TO MODIFY' COLOR SCHEME 7
 READ
 CLEAR
```

command should be completed with return key now it complete with esc

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the SELECT command that's putting the data into the array. Rather, you're using the old style @ commands to do your data entry. I imagine to make that work properly, you'll need to change some of the SET commands. My first guess is that you need to SET KEYCOMP TO DOS, but that's a guess.

Comment: Investigate 'ON KEY LABEL'